# Issue with Creating Multi Tables in Mysql Database using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Can you please let me know if it is possible to create multipile tables in mysql database by SQL command in PHPMYADMIN? I already tried this command

```
CREATE TABLE one (name VARCHAR(30), age INTEGER, height FLOAT, date DATETIME), 
CREATE TABLE two (name VARCHAR(30), age INTEGER, height FLOAT, date DATETIME),
CREATE TABLE three (name VARCHAR(30), age INTEGER, height FLOAT, date DATETIME);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE one (name VARCHAR(30), age INTEGER, height FLOAT, date DATETIME); 
CREATE TABLE two (name VARCHAR(30), age INTEGER, height FLOAT, date DATETIME);
CREATE TABLE three (name VARCHAR(30), age INTEGER, height FLOAT, date DATETIME);
```

but I am encountering with syntax error message.

Comment: which syntax error are you getting?

Comment: This should work correctly. Be sure to select the proper database in PhpMyAdmin first, then run your second set of commands in the "SQL" tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS one;
CREATE TABLE one (name VARCHAR(30), age INTEGER, height FLOAT, date DATETIME); 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS two;
CREATE TABLE two (name VARCHAR(30), age INTEGER, height FLOAT, date DATETIME);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS three;
CREATE TABLE three (name VARCHAR(30), age INTEGER, height FLOAT, date DATETIME);
```

Comment: Thanks rajat it works now, can you please  also let me know how to insert data to tables now?

Comment: simple syntex `INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)`